# Encoding JWT key for APNS using rails RPUSH gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-push-notifications, jwt

I want to use JWT key to send push notifications

I searched for libraries implementing JWT token standard: https://jwt.io/

So I found ruby-jwt gem: https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt

But it seems that it can't create key with the structure required by Apple:

```
{
    "alg": "ES256",
    "kid": "ABC123DEFG"
}
{
    "iss": "DEF123GHIJ",
    "iat": 1437179036
 }
```

Also, how should I use APNs Auth Key (.p8 mime-type) to generate JWT token?

Any advices are welcome

**UPDATE**

Ok, I found out, that it is possible to add custom fields to header
https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/pull/8/files

Anyways, how should I use APNs Auth Key? Does rpush gem supports jwt tokens?

Comment: according to this issue, rpush doesn't support this as of now: https://github.com/rpush/rpush/issues/322

Answer (score 0):

here is ruby gem for new p8 format that uses http2 and jwt https://github.com/andrewarrow/p8push

Comment: Late at the party but I'm trying to get p8push to work. My notifications are never marked "sent". But if I test everything with "Push Notifications Tester" and same parameters, I get notifications on my iPhone. My server runs Ubuntu 16.04.6, with all parameters hardcoded in a simple REST (Sinatra) call. Latest p8push version.